# Communicate OPC Server

Tags: iot, dashboard, opc

Is there any dashboard solutions available to communicate OPC Server directly (OLE for Process Control + Used in Industrial Standards)? 
If so please suggest the dashboard vendor name.

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://thingsboard.io/, an open-source IOT platform. The IOT Gateway service gathers the time-stamped data (telemetry) from OPC UA servers on my network. Thingsboard stores all the telemetry in a open-source, fault tolerant database, and provides web-based, customizable dashboards for visualization.

Check out the live demo.